# How to open a "Cached Theme.pak" in a Chrome theme CRX

Tags: google-chrome, compression, themes, chromium

I am able to open CRX files by changing the file extension to .zip, but when I am trying to get files that make up a theme, I can't find any. I'm assuming their in a file with the name "Cached Theme.pak", since that's the only file I haven't checked. The problem is that I can't open this file, I have already tried using 7-Zip and WinRAR, I also even tried changing the PAK file extension to ZIP, but that didn't work either. Does anyone know how I can open this file?